# Processing 3.5.4 Export Application MacOS/Win Solution

Tags: export, processing

I had some issues with export of applications from Processing 3.5.4 on my MacOS. I searched if someone has posted the answer and I did not find any.

The problem was that the exported application did not run at all.

Comment: Hey Polina, if you're trying to post a solution that you found, please post it as an answer to this question. Otherwise this question will appear as if it needs an answer. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have the folder "data" in Contents/Java/ for MacOS App [folder of app for MacOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2bcs.png) and just in a folder with exe and source for Windows app [folder of app for Win](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxFxg.png). If not, create it and paste all extra images/sounds/etc. And try to run.

This solved my problem.